# How do I update a field (specifically date) when running a macro (specifically e-mail)

Tags: sql, vba, email, ms-access

I'm using one of the default access templates (contacts) and want to capture the date any time I click the e-mail button on a contact.  This runs a macro that calls the `EMailDatabaseObject` action.  I want to add an action that would run the query:

```
UPDATE CONTACTS SET lastemail = GetDate() WHERE ID=[ID];
```

I'm also not sure how to get it to put the ID field in there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of different ways of doing what you want.
I am going to list out three different alternatives for you.

**1. If you really want to use an embedded macro, you can do the following:**

1. Add the field `LastEmail` (Date) in the table `Contacts`.
2. Add the field to the form `Contact Details`.
3. Set the new field's property `Visible = False` in the form.
4. In the embedded macro, you can add a line to do the following :

   ```
   SetValue
       Item = [LastEmail]
       Expression = Now()
   ```

**2. You can use a combination of code and macros :**

1. You can go into the VBA editor (`ALT+F11`).
2. Insert a module and paste the following function :

   ```
   Function updateEmailTime()
       CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE CONTACTS SET lastemail = Now() WHERE ID=" & [Form_Contact List].[ID]
   End Function
   ```
3. Edit the embedded macro in the `OnClick` event to include a line for `RunCode` and use your new function `updateEmailTime`.

**3. If you want to do it entirely in code, you can replace the embedded macro in the `OnClick` event of the Email button for an `[Event Procedure]` with the following :**

```
Private Sub cmdEmail_Click()
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    ' Send the email
    With objMail
        .To = [Form_Contact List].E_mail_Address
        .Subject = "This is the subject."
        .Body = "This is the body."
        .Display '(If you want to see the email and send it yourself)
        '.Send '(If you want to send the email without seeing it)
    End With

    ' Update the time.
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE CONTACTS SET lastemail = Now() WHERE ID=" & [Form_Contact List].[ID]

    ' Clean up the objects
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

I would tend to do things with code rather than using Access's macro builder. You'll find that everything is easier. Make sure to create the new field in your table for all the alternatives.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I'm all for using code, but where do I put that?  There's an OnClick action when I go to design view for the form (that's where I can get to the macro.)  I'm assuming I can use this to run any SQL query I'd like?  Sorry, I'm very familiar with SQL but struggle with using that knowledge to do anything useful in access.

Comment: No worries, I edited the answer to include the alternatives with details. There is a lot of different ways of doing this. But yes, you would need to change the `OnClick` to whichever method you prefer.

Comment: For method 3, when you select an `EventProcedure` and go to Edit Mode, it should bring up the VBA editor with the focus on a blank sub in the form module. You just need to replace the empty sub.